# SMTP server response: 530 5.7.57

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a mail with php. I watched in the internet to find a solution and I found diferent ways but not one helped me. When I come to the code where it should send the mail I got following error:

> mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [AM4PR08CA0065.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com]"

mail call:

```
$mailAdr = "name@company.ch";
$subject = "subject";
$msg = "message!";
$header = 'FROM: My WebSite <name@company.ch>';
mail($mailAdr, $subject, $msg, $header);
```

I set the right smtp and port. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error message says it clearly: the SMTP server doesn't accept emails from unauthenticated user. You need to have an email account on that server (the same server usually serves IMAP or POP3; use the same username and password you use to read the email from the server). However, there is no way to send emails through this server using the standard PHP function [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You need to use a mail sending library ([SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) f.e.)

Comment: which mail sending libary you recommend? @axiac

Comment: @NiZelooer use Swiftmailer... but that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: ok I try it. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Why not @Stony?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add your FROM header that is missing in your code.

```
<?php
$header = 'From: My Website <info@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $nachricht, $header);
?>
```

Comment: It's not missing I set it in php.ini

Comment: Then please post the entry or test it with the header. Normally you should set the header in the mail request.

Comment: Why you made before the = a point ? And why you add at the end the `"\r\n"`?

Comment: In the example where more then one header ;) you need the line bread the header are devided by that line breaks.

Comment: ah ok so for my example I only have one header so I don't need the 
`\r\n`

Comment: as you see in the question I changed it. Now I set the header in the php file and not in the php.ini. But I got still the same error.